# Can you encode/decode image into WebP in Pure Java without any native library?

Tags: java

Can you encode/decode image into WebP in Pure Java without any native library?

What I've seen are implementations that use external library, either embedded or otherwise to the library.

Comment: You can, but it will most likely be slower than a native library.

Comment: You can do anything in any programming language, given sufficient effort. Are you willing to write your own codec? Probably not

Answer (score 1):

There is a [git repo](https://github.com/b4rtaz/android-webp-encoder) which encode decodes webp with animation support but It does not support the transparent background yet. I had to set image background as solid color to use those image for encode decode.

To make changes in this project or add alpha channel support (transparency) you should learn about [googl's webp container specifications](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container)

PS: I have fixed the alpha channel issue and published to github and jitpack/maven. https://github.com/KishorJena/Webp_Transcoder